# How to set a rule in pattern matching to change a string from one form to another

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want to define a rule that will change a particular type of string to another form.
For example:-
a string having `R1~~"=C"~~"C"("OO|O")~~R2 -> R1~~"C"(O)~~"C"~~R2`

Comment: Could you post the complete example (i.e. with original and target string)? Plus, have you looked at the documentation of [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringReplace.html)?

Comment: What are the specific transformation rules you want to apply?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, learnmathematica. I hope you will learn a lot here. In order to improve your experience here, you can do a lot yourself. Please try to describe your problem as well as you can and also try to show some effort. Your current question looks a bit like "give me the codez fast!" and I'm sure that's not your intention. You will also notice that comments will trickle in pretty quickly after posting a question. Please, make it a habit to check your question regularly, especially in the beginning, and provide feedback as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite clear what you are aiming to do, but perhaps this would work:

```
StringReplace["r1abc=CxxC(00)r2xyz",
 R1__ ~~ "=C" ~~ x___ ~~ "C(00)" | "C(0)" ~~ R2__ :> 
  R1 <> "C(O)" <> x <> "C" <> R2]
```

> r1abcC(O)xxCr2xyz

Comment: You can have a single `RuleDelayed` instead of two using `...~~"C(00)" | "C(0)"~~...`

Comment: @ kguler - already put that in, thanks